# How can I determine at runtime if an interface member is implemented?

Tags: c#, interface, implementation

I have an interface called `IStructuredReader` that reads some structured data from a file and displays it in a form.  It has a member called `Sync()` that, when implemented, scans the data for a user-specified data pattern.

Some implementations of `IStructuredReader` don't have sync capability.  Those implementations throw `NotImplementedException` for the `Sync()` method.  I would like to be able to check for this method being implemented, so that I can dim the button on the form if it is not.

I can think of a number of ways that this could be done, all of which seem clumsy and complicated:

1. Separate the `Sync` method into its own interface, inherit it for those implementations that support the capability, and attempt to cast the reader object to it to identify the capability,
2. Write a `NotImplementedAttribute`, decorate the member with it, and check for the presence of the attribute using Reflection,
3. Add a `HasSyncCapability` boolean property to the interface.

Is there a canonical way this is done?

Comment: I would throw out #2.  If nothing else, it's just more work for no concrete benefit.

Comment: Is it possible for the methods that don't support it to just do nothing, instead of throwing?  Does `Sync` need to return something, or does the caller act differently based on whether `Sync` is defined?

Comment: `CanSync` would be a better name, and a `TrySync` may be a better choice for the sync operation. It can simply fail for unsyncables, always returning `false`.

Comment: Could you change your interface into an abstract class and have it return false unless HasSyncCapability is overriden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you really should have two interfaces.  Your `Sync()` method is obviously adding functionality over your base interface, which suggests that this is really a separate concern, as it's not a requirement of `IStructuredReader`.  I would suggest adding a second interface for the types which support this, which would then be easy to check for in your view layer.

Comment: [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) to the rescue...

Comment: I'm not fully agree with you. Look at the `Stream` class. There are no interface for Seek. In this situation it is more intuitive to have a `CanSeek` or `CanRead`. Instead of `ISeekable` and so on. So I suggest here to use a `CanSync`.

Comment: @CSharper There are quite a few (often valid) criticisms about the `Stream` class - I wouldn't argue that it's a good sample to use as a design.  For example, see: http://turingmachinesareprograms.blogspot.com/2009/09/net-design-mistakes-streams.html

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Did you read the book http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1358423808&sr=8-1&keywords=framework+design+guidelines? There is clearly explained, why they didn't use interface. You had to cast the `Stream` in every interface, this results in more complex code...

Comment: @CSharper Yes, I've looked at it.  That decision predates extension methods, however - the .NET world has changed today, so all of the arguments they used don't apply in a C# 3+ world.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is for the interface to expose the methods that will be implemented, so the cleanest solution I see is to create another interface called maybe `Syncronizable` with just that method. If your object implements that interface you know the method is there, and this is not clumsy at all. Using reflection or the extra attribute are indeed not as clean as solutions, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't go for those if it makes your life easier ;)